# Displaying a non-html encoded partial view in a Ajax Response

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to do the following:

1. I have a Ajax.BeginForm that sends the content of a textarea to a action/controller
2. The action does "stuff", and returns a PartialView
3. The Ajax.BeginForm has InsertionMode = ...Replace so the response from the server is populated in a div

Everything work's fine. The controller is hit, the code does what it should, and then returns a PartialView

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewPost(FormCollection fc)
{
    //...some code
    return PartialView("_Post", dc);
}
```

The problem is when the response is populated on the client side, it's all HTML encoded. How do I prevent this from happening?

I'm trying not to write a separate jQqery handler, JSON etc.

Thanks!

Comment: really not clear what issue is. what do you mean `it's all HTML encoded`? You should receive html string .

Comment: Hi Charlie, the response when displayed on the page shows it literally - i.e. with the html characters < > (it's encoded) etc rather than as actual html output

Answer (score 0):

OK, all I needed to do was

```
string ret = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(this.RenderPartialViewToString("_Post", dc));
```